# Parse REST Response Using PHP / CURL

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I'm trying the REST API here: https://www.semrush.com/api-analytics/ , specifically the Organic Results, but no matter what I've tried, I can't seem to manipulate the data. Can someone tell me how to do this? I've tried SimpleXML, JSON, and even breaking up the response via explode() but I must be missing something because all I can do is push the result to the beginning of an array and not actually break it up.

This is my current code:

```
    $url = "http://api.semrush.com/?type=phrase_organic&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&display_limit=10&export_columns=Dn,Ur&phrase=seo&database=us";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
```

With the result being:

```
string 'Domain;Url
site-analyzer.com;https://www.site-analyzer.com/
woorank.com;https://www.woorank.com/
hubspot.com;http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/33164/6-SEO-Tools-to-Analyze-Your-Site-Like-Google-Does.aspx
seoworkers.com;http://www.seoworkers.com/tools/analyzer.html
seositecheckup.com;http://seositecheckup.com/
site-seo-analysis.com;http://www.site-seo-analysis.com/
webseoanalytics.com;http://www.webseoanalytics.com/free/seo-tools/web-seo-analysis.php
seocentro.com;http://www.seocentro.com/t'... (length=665)
```

Is there a simple way to break this up so I can manipulate or reformat the response?

Comment: Why `explode` is not working? I tried here and worked: `$str="Domain;Url searchengineland.com;http://searchengineland.com/guide/what-is-seo wikipedia.org;..."; $arr = explode(';', $str); var_dump($arr); `. I got the result just fine. `$arr[1] = "Domain"`...

Comment: is this exactly how your response is formatted? please update your question with the result of `var_dump($result)` and view-source then copy the result if you are checking this in a browser.

Comment: Just a sidenote: **That** is **not** a REST API. It's just a simple API, but not **RESTful** at all.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Weeeeelll... it **is** using stateless authentication, but that's about it..

Comment: I've updated with var_dump() and furnished the new result. I think I'm having parsing trouble because there is an ASCII carriage return and newline being inserted in between each entry: Domain;Url&#13;&#10;site-analyzer.com;htt... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly explode the new-line characters in order to get to the `csv` structure, then parse it, as `csv`

```
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $response) as $key=>$line){

    if ($key!=0) {
        list($domain,$url) = str_getcsv($line,';');
        print 'Domain: ' . $domain . ', URL: ' . $url . PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Using the sample response from https://www.semrush.com/api-analytics/#phrase_organic,
the above will output

```
Domain: wikipedia.org, URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization
Domain: searchengineland.com, URL: http://searchengineland.com/guide/what-is-seo
Domain: moz.com, URL: http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo
```

The `if` statement is there to filter out the first line, the csv header.

Comment: Thanks! Also if any of the answers helped don't forget to mark one as the accepted answer, so future users can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we could explode by space `" "`, then by `;`

```
$response = explode(" ", trim(str_replace("Domain;Url", "", $response)));

$readableResponse = [];

foreach($response as $r)
{
  $e = explode(";", $r);
  $readableResponse[$e[0]] = $e[1];
}

print_r($readableResponse);
```

Ie. [Live on phpsandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9dfb34ab2a54ebbea1c723f58e58f1986ae907e1)

```
[searchengineland.com] => http://searchengineland.com/guide/what-is-seo
[wikipedia.org] => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization
....
```

Comment: In order to get away with this you will need to know the escape character for strings, in the event an actual semi-colon is part of the data.  semrush should have their documentation for responses somewhere.

Comment: @Flosculus yes, their response is non sense

Comment: @old_mountain ... hey how would I parse a basic semrush API response? 

Here is the response itself (Database;Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost;PLA uniques;PLA keywords
us;seobook.com;98072;14085;14300;62233;0;0;0;0;0)